# Ruby not allowing me to compare values

Tags: ruby

I made the code below, but when I run it, including if I pick the correct number, the console prints the debug. Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

```
puts 'Welcome to the number guessing game.  I will pick a number between 1-100.  It will be your job to guess the number.  If you are incorrect, I will tell you if your guess is higher or lower than my number, I will let you know.'
puts "Time to guess!"
mine = (rand(1..100))
puts mine
grabber = gets.chomp! 
if mine == grabber
  puts 'That\'s it!'
else 
  print 'debug'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing values of two different types. `gets` returns a string, `rand(1..100)` returns an integer. You can't compare them directly. You need to convert them to the same type, either both integer or both string.

Try using `to_i` on the string to convert it to an integer:

```
if mine == grabber.to_i
```

Comment: How it worked then `2.5.3 :003 > 3 == 'sd' => false` ?

Comment: @ray What are you asking? `3 == 'sd'` is, of course, false.

Comment: @meagar sorry my bad, I thought OP is reporting exception but he was reporting bug. Comparison is done anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As @meagar said, you are comparing different types (a string from `gets` and a number from `rand`) which will always returning false.

That being said, you have a couple of different ways to coerce/convert datatypes in ruby.

The most common one, as @maeger showed, is using `to_i`, however it can lead to some strange behaviours as any string that isn't easily parsed as an integer will return 0.

```
2.5.3 :001 > 'potato'.to_i 
=> 0
2.5.3 :002 > '0xff'.to_i 
=> 0
```

If you want to avoid this you can use `Integer(arg)`, this is actually a method defined in `Kernel` that will do its best to verify if the string is actually convertible into an integer and if it fails it will raise an `ArgumentError`.

```
2.5.3 :001 > Integer('potato')
=> ArgumentError (invalid value for Integer(): 'potato')
2.5.3 :002 > Integer('2') 
=> 2
2.5.3 :003 > Integer('0xff') # Hexadecimal
=> 255 
2.5.3 :004 > Integer('0666') # Octal
=> 438
2.5.3 :005 > Integer('0b1110') # Binary
=> 14
```